# Matching one variable and its slope on a surface in 3-dimensions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the following equation (also viewable and more nicely formatted at the bottom of page 5 of [this PDF](https://www.fs.fed.us/pnw/pubs/pnw_rn533.pdf)):

$$z = \frac{2500}{ \left(\frac{ \left (\frac{X^{2}}{(Y - 4.5) + 0.954038 - 0.0558178X + 0.000733819X^{2}}\right )}{0.109757 + 0.00792236X + 0.000197693X^{2}}\right )} + 4.5$$

That translates to this surface (with si = z, age = x, and height = y):

$\hskip2in$[image]

My problem is that I want to find si (hereafter Site Index) with only height and the slope of height. Conceptually I have been able to make inroads to doing this in two dimensions if I model the individual SI curves as a polynomial. I also understand a little bit spatially what it is I want to accomplish, which is demonstrated in the below image.

On the left of this image is the original publication showing discrete Site Index curves and I have highlighted holding height constant at 30 (purple), 70 (orange), and 130 (yellow). On the right are the same constant heights in three dimensions. In two dimensional space, for a given Site Index curve, I can obviously find the age with ease. My problem is that I actually have a given constant height and the change in height (slope) and need to match those up with the right "curve".

To do this I *think* I need to take the second derivative of the original equation (first to get down to the two dimensional space on the left, and a second time to match up the slope) but I am now pretty stuck. I have been looking at the right image a long time and some how have a block - I cannot figure out with respect to what variable I would be differentiating(?), and if this is a partial derivative problem or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to *assume* that by "change in height", you mean $m:=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$, when $y$ is considered as a function of $x$ and $z$ (so $z$ is held constant as the derivative with $x$ is being taken). Now let's simplify the notation considerably, by introducing two new functions in $x$, and replacing the nasty constants by tidy letters: Let $a = 2500, b= 4.5$, and let $$p = −4.5+0.954038−0.0558178x+0.000733819x^2\\q = 0.109757+0.00792236x+0.000197693x^2$$
Then your expression is $$z - b= \frac a{\left[\frac {\left(\frac {x^2}{y + p}\right)}q\right]} = \frac {aq(y+p)}{x^2}$$ or
$$y + p= \frac {x^2(z-b)}{aq} $$
Hence $$m + p' = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + p' = \frac{z-b}a\frac {2xq - x^2q'}{q^2}$$
Solving for $z$ again, $$z -b = \frac{aq^2(m+p')}{2xq - x^2q'}$$
where $p'$ and $q'$ are the derivatives of $p$ and $q$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: I made a huge mistake - I didn't include the parentheses in the equation. It's in the pdf. I didn't really notice the discrepancy until I started going through your answer. I understand the approach though and that's what I really needed. Thank you for such a clear answer.

Comment: @HFBrowning - it's alright. For completeness, I've changed my answer to match the corrected expression.

Comment: That is so helpful, thank you! I am very much brushing off math cobwebs with this project.